# Why the same simple product with the same amount added twice into sales_flat_order_item table!

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order, onestepcheckout, items, sales-quote

Sales Flat order Item table : [image]
Magento Order View Products Block :[image]
An other one, this time with 3 SAME SIMPLE ROWS:[image]
I recently had two orders which I see the exact same simple product created twice with the same amounts in the `sales_flat_order_item` table. But this causes a complication like the calculation of supply needs. Since the ordered items and their amounts are gathered from this table, it counts the simple product supply need as 4 instead of 2 cause of this duplication. As you know the parent Configurable is also added in that table and it is added only once. Just after the config there is the first simple product with `ordered_qty` 2 and other products in between and at the end the same simple again with the same `parent_item_id` pointing the configurable in the table.

I checked the `createOrder` function there is nothing in there, it was never edited already. And this occurs only with one simple product so far. With all the other products I dont have any problems like this.

If there is any body who had the same issue please guide me to the correct solution.

Cheers

Comment: Could you post screenshots of the Order in Magento (specifically the items table) and also the offending rows in the sales_flat_order_item table?

Comment: Added the screenshots.

Comment: I think problem comes from the QUOTE, these simple are added to quote more than once and of course when quote is converted to order it gets all items from quote and creates the simples multiple times. I use onepagecheckout but this issue started to appear this month and only 2 out of over 300 orders.